# How to get SharePoint Site authentication information to use it in an ASP.NET website which is integrated inside that SharePoint Site?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have integrated my ASP.NET website into a SharePoint Site by using an IFrame in the SharePoint Page via a Content Editor Web Part. The ASP.NET web application doesn't have any authentication & authorization implemented in it.But the SharePoint site is having some authentication implemented. Now my requirement is how to get and use that SharePoint authentication information in my ASP.NET web application programmatically to do some code manipulations based on the authenticated user level.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The 'Right' way of doing it would be to redevelop your site as a collection of Application pages.  This allows you to limit permissions to Site Collection Administrators, or just about any level of SharePoint Authentication.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee231581(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee231581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This allows you to use the SharePoint object model directly in your 'web' application.

It's a bit complicated to shift from a traditional web application to getting all the pieces running under the Sharepoint _layouts folder, but its worth the time spent and pretty easy to update.

It should be noted that your existing IIS website would be removed and the pages re-homed to that layout folder, via a SharePoint Feature containing your application pages.